# C - print in Stream array byte with variable size

Tags: c, printf, arrays

I'm designing a system where I read from a SD card and send the information via Bluetooth.

To do that, firstly I ready data from a SD card and store the bytes in an array byte of a fixed length:

```
char final_name[17];
```

And to send it via Bluetooth, I defined the Bluetooth as a stream, and I'm calling printf to send data:

```
fprintf(BLUETOOTH, final_name);
```

The **problem** here:

This function was designed to work with:

```
int fprintf(FILE *stream, const char *format, …);
```

so this works perfect and only 8 bytes are sent:

```
fprintf(BLUETOOTH, "name.txt");
```

But I need to send a variable size byte array. I was looking for similar functions to fprintf but where you can expecified the lenght of bytes you want to print, but I couldn't find.

Does anyone knows witha  format simiar to:

int fprintf(FILE *stream, char *format, int lenght);

Comment: I would use sprintf() to format the output into a string, and then send the simple, formatted string to your bluetooth sending routine.

Comment: `fprintf` allows sending arbitrary length string, assuming it is a valid null-terminated string. It looks like you are confused somewhere. Can you give some more details on the requirement?

Comment: Are you sure your finalname is null terminated and is not containing other zeros?

Comment: Just as an aside, you should probably not use a your char array directly as the "fmt" specifier, but instead use "fprintf(BLUE_TOOTH,"%s",final_name)".  It should cut down on compiler warnings, and is less error prone.

Comment: Thanks Eugene Sh. I added in the array byte a 0x00  at the end and as you said the transmision was cut. thank you very much.

And thanks for the recommendation shooper, I will add it as well to my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fwrite` for writing an arbitrary data with a given length into a file (or device file), not only strings.

Comment: I looked for the funcion you recommend on internet, and it is exactly what I was looking for: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fwrite/ The problem is I'm programming a PIC and for some reason, fwrite() doesnt appear in the <stdio.h> of my CCS. But thank you anyway Eugene